# Conditional String matching in pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe `a`

```
  a=pd.DataFrame([[1,'bayern'],[2,'bayern_leverkusen'],[3,'Chelsea'],
                  [4,'manunited'],[5,'westhamunited'],[6,'mancity']]
                  ,columns=['no','club'])
```

I would like to iterate column `club` in such a way that every values in `club` iterates with all the other values in `club` and select only those where there is matching of 4 or more consecutive characters.

For eq `bayern` and `bayern_leverkusen` should be filtered because they contain same substring ***bayern***. Similarily, `manunited` and `westhamunited` should be filtered because they contain they contain same substring ***united***.

**`mancity` should not be filtered because the matching substring `man` is only 3.**

Expected Output:

```
     no    club
 0   1    bayern    
 1   2    bayern_leverkusen
 3   4    manunited
 4   5    westhamunited
```

Comment: how did your attempt at this go?

Comment: To start off with, I am not able to dynamically create substrings of length four or more for every **club** value.

Comment: Also, what's your expected output?

Comment: Sidenote: The German soccer club is `bayer_leverkusen` which has nothing to do with Bayern (=Bavaria) :)

Comment: Added expected output in the question

Comment: This problem could yield multiple sets of clubs. E.g. one set of clubs share 'abcd', another set of clubs share 'efgh', another set of clubs share 'cdef'. These sets of clubs may not even be mutually exclusive. Can you be more concrete with how you identify the clubs?

Comment: The set of clubs could not be mutually exclusive. I will try to explain briefly: I want to iterate each value of club starting from index 0. for eq **bayern** should get compared with every substring of 4 or more characters resulting from other values in column **club**. Next for, **bayern_leverkusen**, the same procedure should be followed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
selector = pd.Series(False,index = a.index)
for first_index,second_index in itertools.combinations(a.index,2):
    club1 = a['club'][first_index]
    club2 = a['club'][second_index]
    for start in range(len(club1)-3):
        if club1[start:start+3] in club2:
            selector[first] = True
            selector[second] = True
            break
new_df = a.loc[selector]
```

Comment: I see result includes mancity. Also, I think you need to replace `first` with `first_index` / `second` with `second_index`.

Comment: Alright, if i change the statement  `if club1[start:start+3] in club2` to if `club1[start:start+4] in club2:`, i am getting desired output. Thank you both of you.